# Max-Plus algebra and hyperplane arrangements

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, fa.functional-analysis, tropical-geometry, tropical-arithmetic

Given an expression in the Max-Plus algebra is it possible to recognize if it represents a continuous piecewise linear (CPWL) function whose polyhedral complex is a hyperplane arrangement?

Or conversely is every CPWL function whose polyhedral complex is a hyperplane arrangement guaranteed to have a certain specific representation in the Max-Plus algebra?

---

There is one answer known to the general version of the second question in the following form (as in, the following doesn't seem to see anything about hyperplane arrangements!):

That for every continuous piecewise linear function $f :\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, there exists a finite set of affine linear functions $\ell_1, \ldots, \ell_k$ and subsets $S_1, \ldots, S_p \subseteq \{1, \ldots, k\}$ (not necessarily disjoint) where each $S_i$ is of cardinality at most $n+1$, such that \begin{equation}\label{eq:hinged-hyperplane}f = \sum_{j = 1}^p s_j \bigg(\max_{i \in S_j} \ell_i\bigg),\end{equation} where $s_j \in \{-1,+1\}$ for all $j=1, \ldots, p$.

Comment: By "whose polyhedral complex" you mean, the regions of non-linearity?

Comment: Yes. Or maybe you might think of "the set of non-differentiable points"

Comment: Okay. So this should very rarely happen. E.g., tropical hyperplanes in the plane are genetically Y-shaped, almost never lines.